# Datatables in OctoberCMS

Tags: datatables, octobercms

It's my first time to develop a website using OctoberCMS and I'm loving it so far. I want to integrate the [Datatables](https://datatables.net/) like [this](https://datatables.test.linkonoid.com/datatables) but it doesn't work for some reason. The styling doesn't even apply to the table. I was trying my luck to find a tutorial but cannot find any over the internet. Thanks in advance!

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf8" src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-9/aliU8dGd2tb6OSsuzixeV4y/faTqgFtohetphbbj0=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<table id="table_id" class="display">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Column 1</th>
            <th>Column 2</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 1 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 1 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Row 2 Data 1</td>
            <td>Row 2 Data 2</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready( function () {
        $('#table_id').DataTable();
    } );
</script>
```

Comment: Move your `<script>` tag containing jQuery so it is placed first, above the `<script>` tag containing DataTables. Also, you can use your browser's console (F12) to check for errors such as "Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined".

Comment: @andrewjames thanks man. I used my browser's console and found out that I have loaded two versions of jQuery. I got an error that says 
`ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function`
Thus, I used the `$.noConflict();` and it worked! Thank you man :) voted up!